# node mongoDb query nested array based on key

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am been trying to find an object in an array based on the key-value, from the data in MongoDB, below is the query from the database, but I only need some specific object, how can achieve that?

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "627261a17acf7875b30d6e34",
    "orderItem": [
      [
        {
          "_id": "626fdb9fd0867e51d613530d",
          "productName": "Handmade jewelry",
          "productPrice": "25.99",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/productimg4.jpg-1651497883882",
          "sellerId": "62470b37f2052b6a6463f9b3",
          "qty": 1
        },
        {
          "_id": "626fdbf4d0867e51d6135389",
          "productName": "Handmade bucket",
          "productPrice": "23.99",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/topSellingImg.jpg-1651497970510",
          "sellerId": "0062470b37f2052b6a6463f9b30",
          "qty": 2
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": "626a5d5dae8851064d4760ac",
          "productName": "handmade bag and show",
          "productPrice": "5",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/productB.jpg-1651137883823", "sellerId": "62470b37f2052b6a6463f9b3",

          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "_id": "626a5dabae8851064d4760af",
          "productName": "hand bag",
          "productPrice": "20",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/homeImg3.jpg-1651137961920",
"sellerId": "0062470b37f2052b6a6463f9b30",
          "qty": 1
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": "626a5d5dae8851064d4760ac",
          "productName": "handmade bag and show",
          "productPrice": "5",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/productB.jpg-1651137883823",
"sellerId": "0062470b37f2052b6a6463f9b30",
          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "_id": "626a5dabae8851064d4760af",
          "productName": "hand bag",
          "productPrice": "20",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/homeImg3.jpg-1651137961920",
"sellerId": "0062470b37f2052b6a6463f9b30",
          "qty": 1
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": "626a5d5dae8851064d4760ac",
          "productName": "handmade bag and show",
          "productPrice": "5",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/productB.jpg-1651137883823",
"sellerId": "0062470b37f2052b6a6463f9b30",
          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "_id": "626a5dabae8851064d4760af",
          "productName": "hand bag",
          "productPrice": "20",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/homeImg3.jpg-1651137961920",
 "sellerId": "62470b37f2052b6a6463f9b3",
          "qty": 1
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": "626a5d5dae8851064d4760ac",
          "productName": "handmade bag and show",
          "productPrice": "5",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/productB.jpg-1651137883823",
"sellerId": "0062470b37f2052b6a6463f9b30",
          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "_id": "626a5dabae8851064d4760af",
          "productName": "hand bag",
          "productPrice": "20",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/homeImg3.jpg-1651137961920",
"sellerId": "0062470b37f2052b6a6463f9b30",
          "qty": 1
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": "626a5d5dae8851064d4760ac",
          "productName": "handmade bag and show",
          "productPrice": "5",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/productB.jpg-1651137883823",
          "qty": 2
        },
        {
          "_id": "626a5dabae8851064d4760af",
          "productName": "hand bag",
          "productPrice": "20",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/homeImg3.jpg-1651137961920",
"sellerId": "0062470b37f2052b6a6463f9b45",
          "qty": 1
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "_id": "626a5d5dae8851064d4760ac",
          "productName": "handmade bag and show",
          "productPrice": "5",
          "proFrontIMAGE": "https://omarjbtbucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/productB.jpg-1651137883823",
 "sellerId": "62470b37f2052b6a64637788",
          "qty": 2
        },
        
      ],
      
      
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Here is my code sample from the node

```js
router.get("/orders", async (req, res) => {
  const { sellerID } = req.query;
  try {
    const order = await SellerOrder.find({
      sellerId: sellerID ,
    });
    res.status(200).json(order);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error + "error fetching data");
  }
});
```

Comment: And the input you want to enter in order to get this expected result....

Comment: thanks @turivishal, my expected result, should be list of object that has the same sellerId

Comment: thanks @nimrodserok, please i dont get that, can you please explain better

Comment: Only two items have sellerId...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For filter, you can try the nested `$elemMatch` operator because your data has nested array,
Try aggregation operator to filter array in projection, you can add your required fields as well in projection,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `orderItem`, set initial value as a blank array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of first-level array to check `sellerId` and filter array
- `$concatArrays` to concat current array with filtered array

```
const order = await SellerOrder.find({
  orderItem: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        sellerId: sellerID
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  orderItem: {
    $reduce: {
      input: "$orderItem",
      initialValue: [],
      in: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$$this",
              cond: {
                $eq: ["$$this.sellerId", sellerID]
              }
            }
          },
          "$$value"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  // add other projection fields here
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ITCyHvKV4l_)